# Substitute __proto__ of DOM Element Object

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, prototype, polymer

So basically I would like to extend a certain type of DOM elements by the following code:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
var proto = Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype);
proto.newMethod = function() {console.log("Good.");};
proto.newConst = Math.PI / 2;
element.__proto__ = proto;
```

This code works in Chrome, Firefox and IE11 (IE10 not tested, but it will probably work), but I'm not sure whether it is proper JavaScript and whether it will continue to work in the future, because anyway this code is hacking DOM elements which is partially outside JavaScript. Could someone give explanation on how it works? I don't fully understand that, and I need to know if this method is robust. Thanks.

---

OK, to make things clearer, I know I should use `Object.create()` to specify prototype, but the real problem is that element objects are special and it's impossible to do that. The above code is more like a workaround, and this is why I'm asking this question.

---

Google's Polymer mutates `__proto__` of DOM objects ([code, line 259](https://github.com/Polymer/CustomElements/blob/master/src/CustomElements.js)):

```
function implement(element, definition) {
  if (Object.__proto__) {
    element.__proto__ = definition.prototype;
  } else {
    customMixin(element, definition.prototype, definition.native);
    element.__proto__ = definition.prototype;
  }
}
```

So, should I trust this method because Google uses it?

Answer (score 2):

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

> The **__proto__** property is deprecated and should not be used.  Object.getPrototypeOf should be used instead of the **__proto__** getter to determine the **[[Prototype]]** of an object.  Mutating the **[[Prototype]]** of an object, no matter how this is accomplished, is strongly discouraged, because it is very slow and unavoidably slows down subsequent execution in modern JavaScript implementations.  However, Object.setPrototypeOf is provided in ES6 as a very-slightly-preferred alternative to the **__proto__** setter.

In general, it is a bad practice to modify native prototypes like Array, String and even HTMLElement, details are described [here](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/), but if you control everything in the current context you can modify the prototypes by adding, on your own risk, some additional functional to achieve what you want. If you can guarantee that your code is not in conflict with some other code and the performance footprint is negligible then you are free to choose your path.

Your approach:

```
SomeHTMLElementInstance.__proto__ = newPrototype;

// or a general case like:

SomeHTMLElementPrototypeConstructor.prototype.newMethod = function () {
    // Do something here
}
```

Recommended approach:

```
var SomeElementWrapper = function (someParams) {
    this.container = document.createElement('SomeHTMLElement');
}

SomeElementWrapper.prototype.someMethod = function () {
    // Do something with this.container without modifying its prototype
}
```

Comment: I don't think mutating `__proto__` is a problem, because even if `__proto__` setter is not available, I can still use `Object.setPrototypeOf()`. The problem is with DOM...

Comment: Whether `__proto__` is going to be deprecated is not yet set into stone. It is specified in the draft of ES6: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-B.2.2.1

Comment: But I'm not modifying native prototypes... I make copies of them and only modify the copies. So the problem is really with DOM but not other things.

Comment: You are right, but it's just a special case of modifying native prototypes but applied for instances, I added some code examples of the recommended approach for this problem

Comment: Hmmm. [This article](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/), from the second link you give, is actually more helpful to me.